# Hamburger menu issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a hamburger menu in my project, it works properly in my first attempt, when I add that same code to my current attempt it does not work, is there anyone available who could take a look and help me?

I have been working on this project for two weeks, have tried ten or so different ways to add a hamburger menu, only had one attempt work but it will now not work on my completed page with all the details

here is the github link https://github.com/sdoull/https---github.com-sdoull-project1.git

Comment: Paste here the code that does not work. Maybe we can all eat together.

Comment: Show what you tried. Use the <> icon to add a minimal executable example of the HTML, CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, `stylesheet` is used for CSS files, and `script` is used for JavaScript files.

Replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.js">
```

to

```
<script src="home.js"></script>
```